# Create dynamically Bitmap with Canvas (Android, Java)

Tags: android, bitmap

I have to implement a function that allow me to draw some Bitmap on surfaceView, this is a part of my code:

```
 public void DrawMarker(float coordX, float coordY){
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapRotated, coordX, coordY, paint);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); 
 }
```

This code allow me to draw a bitmap in a certain position (x,y) of the screen, the problem is that I call dynamically this function (for example 5 times), because I need to draw a Bitmap everytime I touch the screen, I don't understand why the images don't remain on the screen at each touches.

At each touches the images disappear and appear again, but at last the cycle (es. 5 times) I can see only some image and not all.

The situation is different if I draw some points with this function:

```
 public void DrawMarker(float[] coordsF){
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawPoints(coordsF,paint);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); 
 }
```

In this case all point remail on the screen.

**** EDIT 1 ****

```
/* Bind of onTouchEvent*/
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        /* The Y coordinate must be adjusted because is moved downwards for the menu size */
        float coordX = event.getX();
        float coordY = event.getY();

        if (tap < MAXTAP) {
            DrawMarker(coordX, coordY);
            tap++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void DrawMarker(float coordX, float coordY){
    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coordX, coordY, paint);
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

***** SOLUTION *****

```
    /* Draw Bitmap everytime I touch the screen */
    public void DrawMarker(List<Coordinates> coords){
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        for(int i=0; i < coords.size(); i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.get(i).coordX, coords.get(i).coordY, paint);
        }
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
     }
```

Comment: see `lockCanvas` documentation: *"The content of the Surface is never preserved between unlockCanvas() and lockCanvas(), for this reason, every pixel within the Surface area must be written."*

Comment: @pskink For this reason i call this function dinamically, everytime that I touch the screen I save the coords in a structure, and I redraw all Bitmap...

Comment: so you have to call `drawBitmap` multiple times between lock ... unlock

Comment: Look my edited code, this code doesn't work, why?

Comment: you are drawing your bitmap only once, you have to draw it multiple times

Comment: Ok i'm confused, sorry... Could you help me to understand with an example ? I don't understand what I must do

Comment: if you want to see your bitmap 5 times at different positions you have to call `Canvas#drawBitmap` 5 times between `lockCanvas` and `unlockCanvasAndPost`